# Can we convert h265 video to JSON?

Tags: json, h.264, hevc

I'm in search of h265/H264 video to json in effective way. I understood binary data can be converted to JSON but using base64. I'm interested to know is there any way we can define entire 90 minutes H265 video in JSON and then transfer it seamlessly over internet? Making chunks of data based on timestamps and then define encoding details for each video chunk as json object and define correlation between those json objects in JSON file. A player which can read each chunk separately when streaming, only upon streaming entire first chunk(piece) allows user to load immediate chunk in SSL communication between client(browser) and streaming server. I might sound very naive but are there any options to do so?

Comment: why would you even want to do this? whats wrong with current streaming protocols/methods. JSON is meant to transfer structured, serialised data in one request. Not streams/chunks of video/audio.

Comment: No.............

Comment: If a large 3D dataset can be stored in JSON and read through web, why can't a video? Just asking!